# Red underline res folder in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have the situation shown the following picture.
Project built successfully, but it's just annoying to see the red error warning.

[image]

How do I solve it?

Comment: your drawable folder structure seems messed up. goto folder structure and make sure, all the hdpi,mdpi, sub folder fall inside a single drawable folder. easy fix is to go directly in file explorer and fix it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: See the Picture]

Please Invalidate Caches and restart your IDE

Answer (score 3):

The naming of the file also counts, remove all hyphens if there are any

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I'm seeing same picture. Gradle sync or Android studio restart helps me.